# GDI, About alpha bitmap

Tags: c++, gdi

My question is:
After selected a alpha bitmap into a memory DC,  then use DrawText function,  but the text can't show.

the code is as follow:

```
CDC memDC;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
memBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc,64,100);
CBitmap *oldmemBitmap=(CBitmap*)memDC.SelectObject(&memBitmap);

CDC memDC1;
memDC1.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
//m_bitmap has alpha channel   64*64
CBitmap *oldmemBitmap1=(CBitmap*)memDC1.SelectObject(&m_bitmap);
memDC.BitBlt(0, 0, 64, 64, &memDC1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


CString str = _T("TEST");
memDC.DrawText(str,str.GetLength(),CRect(0,64,64,36),DT_CENTER|DT_WORDBREAK|DT_NOCLIP);

memDC.SelectObject(oldmemBitmap);

BITMAP bmpData;
memBitmap.GetBitmap(&bmpData);
CImageList imageList;
imageList.Create(bmpData.bmWidth, bmpData.bmHeight, ILC_COLOR32|ILC_MASK, 0, 1);
imageList.Add(&memBitmap, RGB(0, 0, 0));
POINT pt = {0, 0};
imageList.Draw(&dc, 0, pt, ILD_NORMAL);
```

The m_bitmap can be displayed properly, but the "TEST" string can't.  When I commented memDC.BitBlt(...), "TEST" string can be displayed.  why?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess: check the device font, color and background color selected into your context.

"The DrawText function uses the device context's selected font, text color, and background color to draw the text."
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Maybe your color is the same as the background color for some reason, or something like that.
I ruled out the possibility that your bitmap's alpha channel specify total transparency. In this case the text wouldn't appear either.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in the question to answer definitively what's going on, but I can take some educated guesses.

With very few exceptions, GDI does not handle, respect, or preserve alpha channels.  When you do this:

```
CBitmap *oldmemBitmap1=(CBitmap*)memDC1.SelectObject(&m_bitmap);
```

there's a conversion happening because you can't have a bitmap with an alpha channel in a compatible DC.  ("Compatible DC" is a lousy term.  It's actually a device-dependent DC.)

The BitBlt copies the now-opaque bitmap another DC.  So now you have an opaque bitmap in memDC--I'm guessing it's mostly black.

Then you draw text on top of it.  I'm guessing the text is also black, so you now have black text on a black background.

You then add the bitmap to the image list, telling the image list to mask out all the black pixels, which includes the text and the background.  As a result, you don't see the text.  You also don't see the background, but I suspect you didn't expect to see the background because of the alpha channel (which was actually lost).

When you comment out the BitBlt, you end up with an uninitialized background (possibly not-black) and you draw black text on it.  Then you add it to the image list, masking out the black.  The text seems visible only because it's in contrast to the opaque background.

So that answers the "Why?".  I assume now you'd like to know what to do about it.  For that, we'll need more information about what you want to have happen.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I have tried to modify the text color by the SetTextColor function， but still doesn't work. and I use other CDC's member function like memDC.FillSoildRect, They also have no effect.